# Is it possible to use Javamail to receive mails in Android

Tags: android, email, gmail, jakarta-mail

I'm learning Javamail these days following this website:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/

I test the sending & added some extra stuff because it was on Android & it worked!

But things have changed completely when I tried to follow receiving email Tutorial which makes me wonder..

Is it possible to make this code :
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_fetching_emails.htm

works on android but using XML  interface?!

Comment: Yes, it's possible to use JavaMail on Android; make sure you're following the instructions [here](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android).  If it doesn't work, there are debugging tips in the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).  You can also find lots of sample programs on the [JavaMail web site](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Samples), although you'll need to adapt them for Android.  Sorry, I have no idea what "using XML interface" means in this context since I'm not an Android expert.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
public static void receiveEmail(String pop3Host, String storeType, user, String password) {
        try {
            //1) get the session object  
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.pop3.host", pop3Host);
            Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

            //2) create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server  
            POP3Store emailStore = (POP3Store) emailSession.getStore(storeType);
            emailStore.connect(user, password);

            //3) create the folder object and open it  
            Folder emailFolder = emailStore.getFolder("INBOX");
            emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            //4) retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it  
            Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                Message message = messages[i];
                System.out.println("---------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
                System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
                System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
                System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());
            }

            //5) close the store and folder objects  
            emailFolder.close(false);
            emailStore.close();

        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

call your method passing some parameters:

```
String host = "pop.gmail.com";//change accordingly  
String mailStoreType = "pop3";  
String username= "example@gmail.com";  
String password= "xxxxx";//change accordingly  

receiveEmail(host, mailStoreType, username, password);
```

Source: [Steps for receiving the email using JavaMail API](https://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-receiving-email-using-java-mail-api)

Comment: I tested it in AsyncTask extended class & pass one value to ListView as test to the list but I'm receiving null

Comment: @Sarah have you give this permission in your manifest? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: yes, I put a string and assign it to message.getSubject() but I'm receiving null everytime

Comment: @Sarah Does your Inbox have any received emails with subjects? If not try to send an email to that email address with a subject. I don't see any problems in the code.

Comment: @Sarah By the way, using pop3 protocol your emails will be deleted from your inbox once you access it. Try to use IMAP protocol instead.

Comment: @Sarah use this as reference to using IMAP: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-receive-email-using-imap.html

Comment: if I don't use AsyncTask, I'll end up with android.os.networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: I tested the new link & I'm reciving this error now: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1  Process: mailreaderapp, PID: 8557   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()  java.lang.RuntimeException:
Seems it can't sign in...